# Workflow for New Event Registration

Tags: system-workflow-messages, workflow

When I create a new event, I want someone to be notified via email when it is saved.  How best to do this?

I see in the admin console that there is System Workflow Messages under Message Templates, but how do I create a custom System Workflow?

Answer (score 1):

To my Knowledge this is not a straightforward thing - but can be done -

You need to create an extension and use post or postprocess hook

whenever an Event is been saved against database you need to trigger an action to send an email

---

Install Civix

Extension creation:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

Hook reference:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference

I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I'm referring to the actual creation of the event itself, not registering participants.  When the admin creates a new event in the system, I want the event owner to be notified via email.  Seems like a pretty straightforward thing - when a  new event is created, send an email...? But how to do this?

Comment: I have changed the answer please - based on your question - I guess that helps!!!

Comment: Yeah, so that's exactly what I want to do - but have no idea how to do it!! :)